# Form validation possible on this code?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, validation

I would like to know if below form validation is possible to do. My syntax seems ok. if it is possible how do i make it return false and quit the function (or go back to entering the code again)...btw i am no php programmer....

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer', lang("customer"), 'trim|required');
```

This is the validation i need, so if false is returned it will escape the function, and give an error message

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($id = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->get('id')), 
$pincode = intval($this->input->post('spos_note')), 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `cf1` FROM tec_customers WHERE id='$customer_id' AND cf1 = $pincode") or die(mysql_error()), 
'if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0))');
```

If validation is ok it should continue...

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {



        $quantity = "quantity";
        $product = "product";
        $unit_cost = "unit_cost";
        $tax_rate = "tax_rate";

        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $customer_id = $this->input->post('customer_id');
        $customer_details = $this->pos_model->getCustomerByID($customer_id);
        $customer = $customer_details->name;
        $note = $this->tec->clear_tags($this->input->post('spos_note'));

        $total = 0;
        $product_tax = 0;
        $order_tax = 0;
        $product_discount = 0;
        $order_discount = 0;
        $percentage = '%';
        $i = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? sizeof($_POST['product_id']) : 0;
        for ($r = 0; $r < $i; $r++) {
            $item_id = $_POST['product_id'][$r];
            $real_unit_price = $this->tec->formatDecimal($_POST['real_unit_price'][$r]);
            $item_quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$r];
            $item_discount = isset($_POST['product_discount'][$r]) ? $_POST['product_discount'][$r] : '0';
```

Comment: It is my understanding that you need help with the validation. Could you please show the relevant code of the $this->form_validation object?

Comment: if you use any framework ? ie codeigniter,cakephp etc

Comment: it is written in codeigniter (for all i know). I don't understand exactly what you would need for relevant code?

Comment: We need the Code of your $this->form_validation Object how Fuujin asked

Comment: well, as i dont understand what i need to give or post, i can only explain by showing on the site: http://aicit.nl/POS  usr: stefan@aicit.nl pass: 12345678. When in the sales (second icon left) you can enter some product. On the bottom you can choose button: op rekening or betaling to finalize the sale. A modal popup comes up. There a pincode should be given, which needs to be checked against some data in the tables of the db. If it returns true, then the sale continues. Else it shouldn't finish the sale. If needed i can also give ftp. Hope someone is able to help me with this...

Comment: see the link for understanding of form validation in codeigniter... 

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html